# get value from website in mac OS 10.12.1 & iOS 10.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, https

Getting an **error** since the latest update. 
Can't get data returned from https website.

Please help

Code:

```
func GetValueFromWebsite(_ Url: String, ShowError: Bool) -> String {
    var xml:String = ""
    let url = URL(string: Url)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.sendSynchronousRequest(request: request) { data, response, error in
        xml = String(data: data! as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        xml = xml.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
        xml = xml.replacingOccurrences(of: "\r\n", with: "")
    }
return xml
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question with correct iOS version. iOS 10.12.1 doesn't exist.

Comment: how can I edit the title?

Comment: It's mac OS 10.12.1 and  iOS 10.1.1 (on my iPhone)